# Как импортировать проект Visual C++ в Qt Creator или наоборот?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, visual-c++, qtcreator

У меня есть готоый проект в VS на С++ ,знает ли кто-нибудь о такой вещи или об определенном наборе процедур для перемещения проекта из VS в Qt или наоборот? Или как вообще можно организовать разработку интерфейса на Qt для приложения в VS

Comment: Если используется CMake, то достаточно просто перенести. Qt не зависит от QtCreator, с этим фреймворком можно в любой IDE писать

Comment: Поддержу @dlm0n и добавлю: если вы используете ide зависимые инструменты, то можете забыть о переносимости не то что между системами, но и между различными ide. `cmake` же, по-факту, стал стандартной тулой для сборки программ на c и c++ (но не ограничиваясь только этими языками)

Comment: В VS есть же аддон для разработки QT

Comment: @dIm0n, можно, но сложно. Вернее "из коробки" не заработает, а это уже минус. Мне рассказывали, что при билде Qt не хватило диска для временных файлов (несколько сотен гигабайт)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оптимальный вариант для того, чтобы не зависеть от IDE, как уже было отмечено в комментариях, - это использование проектов на CMake.
Плагин Qt для Visual Studio позволяет открыть проект qmake (см. скриншот). Насколько корректно - зависит от сложности *.pro файла. А вот Qt Creator решения Visual Studio не понимает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]